# Bolzano-Weirstrass

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

This is derived of other question where my proof of the Bolzano theorem is as follows

Proof: Suppose that $(a_n)$ is a bounded sequence then we have to show that it has a convergent subsequence. Since it is bounded then it has a finite limit point $c$, for example $c= \limsup  a_n$.

Let define recursively the following sequence of natural number, $n_0=0$ and $n_i=\min(\{n> n_{i-1}:|a_n-c|\le 1/i\})$. Since $c$ is a limit point then the set is non-empty and the $\min$ is well-defined. Then $(a_{n_i})$ is a subsequence of $a_n$ and since $|a_{n_i}-c|\le 1/i$ for all $i\ge 1$ then the sequence converges to $c$, i.e., $(a_{n_i})\rightarrow c$. $\square$

Is this redundant? I think it is correct and also I don't think that I'm using what must be proved in the  proof - indeed, a pretty similar approach is using in my book of analysis. Am I right or  Am I totally off track?

[Definition of limit point of a sequence (which I'm know): For all $\varepsilon >0$ and for all $N$ there is a $n\ge N$ such that $|a_n-c|\le \varepsilon$]

Comment: Again, perhaps we have different versions of things, but BW theorem states: any bounded real sequence has *** (1) a subsequence converging ***  *** (2) a limit point ***   (points (1)-(2) are equivalent and BW theorem can be stated in either form). Thus, in my book, you are too using what must be proved within your proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few "fundamental" theorems are equivalent: Cantor's nested interval theory, the Bolzano Weierestrass theorem, completeness and the monotone convergence theorem. Assume one, and make sure you prove the others with this!

Comment: But in this specifically case the definition of limit point of a sequence can be given without appealing to the Bolzano thm, and the lim sup and lim inf also can be defined in this fashion. So, I cannot see in which manner I'm using what must be proved?

Comment: @JoseAntonio I'm not saying you are, I just brought to light what must be taken care about. If you did, you're fine.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I'm assuming that any non-empty set of real number which is bounded it has a lub, I take completness =)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Does Bolzano Weirstrass theorem work only for "infinite sequence", because in definition it just says "sequence"?

Comment: @Larry The sequences are always (by definition) an infinite tuple $(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)$. If the sequence is eventually constant, then that theorem is immediate, since the sequence contains a constant (convergent) subsequence.